Cartoon/Anime with Avatar-Like Mech-Suits
It was during the same time that Zoids, Yu-gi-oh etc was out, so late 90's most likely hearly 2000's. It was about a team of people that had control of these mech-suits (like the ones in Avatar). They would play team-based games like capture the flag and stuff, and they have tank-track feet to move around, as well as walking. I remember one episode they fought a giant T-rex dinosaur. And that the bad team were in black mechs. 
It isn't Gundam, transformers, zoids, voltron, avanlgion. I've looked on loads of forums and can't find it. 
I think it was either on Sky or the main 1-5 channels. Though it could have also been on CN or 2 other channels that had things like Naruto etc. 

D.I.C.E? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.I.C.E.
Else, you could have a look at this (long) list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_mecha

Heavy Gear? Although it is in 3d

It is Heavy Gear. Thanks, I didn't think this forum would pay off but it did instantly. You rock Jorgel!

@Jorgel - Good job! You should post that as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Heavy Gear

Heavy Gear is a game universe published since 1994 by Canadian publisher Dream Pod 9. It includes a tabletop tactical wargame, a role-playing game and a lesser known combat card game (Heavy Gear Fighter). The setting is also known through the PC-game incarnations published by Activision in 1997 and 1999, developed after Activision lost the rights to the Battletech/MechWarrior series. It also spawned a 40-episodes, 3D-animated TV series in 2001, which featured a much simplified version of the universe developed in the role-playing game.  

Wikipedia Entry
